# Preserving URL when using SSL Redirect for multiple websites pointing to same folder

Tags: ssl, iis-7.5, http-redirect

I have multiple websites pointing to a central folder (IIS 7.5)

company1.domain.com/wo pointing to D:\inetpub\wo

company2.domain.com/wo pointing to D:\inetpub\wo

company3.domain.com/wo pointing to D:\inetpub\wo

All the websites work for both HTTP and HTTPS (if typed manually). However, the sites have to connect via HTTPS.  I want to setup automatic SSL redirect to but am having issues.  I created URL Rewrite rule but since this is only one webconfig file the URL redirects to only one website (not maintaining the URL). 
How do I setup SSL redirect so that the URLs are preserved and all websites point to the same folder? 
Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include the host header when checking if HTTPS is enabled and then redirect to the https URL for the appropriate domain.

Here's an example:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="Force HTTPS - www.domain1.com" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{HTTPS}" negate="true" pattern="^ON$" />
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="\.domain1\.com$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.domain1.com{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Force HTTPS - www.domain2.com" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{HTTPS}" negate="true" pattern="^ON$" />
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="\.domain2\.com$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.domain2.com{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
        <!-- add more rules for other domains if needed -->
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

You can add as many rules for domain names as you want.

**EDIT:** Sorry, I misread your question. In that case it's even simpler:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="Force HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{HTTPS}" negate="true" pattern="^ON$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

No need to check for the host header, just include the host name in the redirect. You only have to make sure that you have SSL certificates for all domain names.

Comment: Thanks for your update.  I tried the suggestions and am closer to a resolution.  

However, the domain does not change only the CNAME.  So I have company1.domain.com/wo; company2.domain.com/wo; etc

In your suggestion, states 

   <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="\.domain1\.com$" />

I tried using the CNAME ("\.company1\.com$" and also ".\company1.domain\.com$" but neither work.

Do you know how I can edit the rule to change only the CNAME of the url?

Thanks again.

Comment: Your second suggestion WORKED like a charm...Thanks million!!